# Range().Cells().Row

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I was troubled by the following code

```
Dim xTRrow as Integer
Dim xTitle as String
Dim xSht as Worksheet
xTRrow = xSht.Range(xTitle).Cells(1).Row
```

I wonder what the last line does. Especially, the `.Row`. In case as such, how do can I run the VBA code line by line to find out what a specific line of code does? I guess something is off with the code. I've tried to display `xTRrow` which should be an integer. But nothing jumps on the screen. I wonder what the last option `.Row` does.

Comment: .Row returns the row number of the specified cell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to using `F8` to step through the code, you can use `debug.print` to display the values of relevant variables before and after the given line. That said as you use VBA, you will be able to recognize what object and method is. Assuming the code works fine and all variables and objects were dimmed and set properly:

```
xSht.Range(xTitle).Cells(1).Row
```

break down as follows:

`xSht` : variable containing a sheet (which sheet we don't know as that part of your code is missing in your question)

`xTitle`: probably the name of a `named range` (which range we don't know as that part of your code is missing in your question)

`Cells(1)`: Cell no; `1` of the above mentionned named range

`Row`: the row of the cell in question

So `xTRrow` should be the row number of the cell in question. (BTW, it really should be `Dim`med as `Long` as Excel can have more rows than `Integer` allows for

Answer (score 0):

## Row Trouble

### Description

The variable '**xTRrow**' is equal to the '**row**' of the '**1**'st '**cell**' of the '**range** '**xTitle**' in the worksheet '**xSht**'. You can make it work by defining the missing data.

### The Code

```
Option Explicit

Sub RowTrouble()

  Dim xSht As Worksheet  ' A Worksheet
  Dim xTitle As String   ' A Range Address (or a Named Range)
  Dim xTRrow As Long     ' A Row - rows are best declared as Long.

'  ' Your code (not yet working)
'  xTRrow = xSht.Range(xTitle).Cells(1).Row

  ' Define the range
  xTitle = "A1:D1"

  ' Create a reference to the worksheet with the name "Sheet1"
  Set xSht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

  ' Your code working
  xTRrow = xSht.Range(xTitle).Cells(1).Row

  ' To display the result in the immediate window
  Debug.Print "The first row in my workbook's range (" & xTitle _
      & ") is equal to " & xTRrow & "."

  ' To display the result in a message box:
  MsgBox "The first row in my workbook's range (" & xTitle _
      & ") is equal to " & xTRrow & "."

  ' To display the result in the sheet:
  xSht.Range("A1") = "The first row in my workbook's range (" & xTitle _
      & ") is equal to " & xTRrow & "."

End Sub
```

### How

Open a new worksheet. Go to Visual Basic Editor and insert a new module into the worksheet. Copy/paste the example into it. Open the **immediate** window to be able to see the result. Run the code.

### Line by Line

Too loop through the code line by line under **Debug** select **Step Into** or just use '**F8**':

[image]